# Parse and rewrite Visual Studio C# source code document character by character

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn

I've been working on learning Roslyn and have made great progress with using the `CSharpSyntaxRewriter` mechanism to work on code.  My goal in the end is to have a customizable coding standards enforcer.  As such, I started with Microsoft's code formatter project from https://github.com/dotnet/codeformatter/releases.  Right now what I'm working on is formatting white space.

The goal here is to learn Roslyn, so I want to write the code to format all of the whitespace instead of using the Formatter built into Visual Studio and Roslyn.

```
Formatter.FormatAsync(document, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

I'm able to parse syntax trees and know I can implement the code necessary to do this using the CSharpSyntaxRewriter, but what I'd like to do is somehow simply get the raw source text for the code, do whatever manipulations are necessary character by character in the source file, and then put the new text back as the document.

However, I cannot figure out if it's even possible to do what I'm trying to do with Roslyn/Visual Studio.  I would have thought so, since the source is simply a text file that's already loaded into Visual Studio, and the 'document' object can be acquired for it.

## Edit

The optimum solution would be a drop down (or context) menu for C# source files that then ran all modifications on the file.  I was unable to link MEF/MPF to any sort of hook that would allow whole-scale modifications of a source file.  As such, I went to a console application.

From what I understand, MEF/MPF can provide single entry points to the source file, whereas the Roslyn interface allows simultaneous access to the entire source file at one time.  I believe that's why Microsoft used Roslyn in order to implement their coding standards enforcer.

As I said, I've only been looking at Roslyn for about a month, so I may be missing something obvious.

Comment: You might consider writing paragraphs, I'm convincedmany people skip your question. Please use some formatting.

Comment: I don't know how Roslyn does things but generally we use Microsoft's Managed Package Framework (MPF) over at CodePlex or more recently MEF Extenstions for that sort of thing.

Comment: Just so we're clear. You want to get a source file, feed it into Roslyn, get that same source file out of Roslyn, and then do manipulation on it? Are you sure you need Roslyn at all?

Comment: Jeroen - sorry, first post, but will add paragraphs in the future (or as soon as I figure out how to edit)

Comment: Guillaume - no, what I'm trying to do is: load the solution into the console app that does the syntax parsing, but then be able to modify the source code either with the CSharpSyntaxRewriter or with a mechanism that lets me go through the code character by character

Comment: MickyD - Thanks for the response and I'll see what I can figure out on that side of things.  However, what I'm trying to do is a single solution for all issues.  I.e. I want to use the CSharpSyntaxRewriter when enforcing the coding standards as to how to name variables, etc, but be able to use raw text modification techniques for other things.

Comment: gerdi - Thanks so much for rewriting in a more friendly manner

Comment: Still unclear: if you're going character by character, why do you need Roslyn at all? You don't need to parse the tokens if you're only interested in characters.

Comment: Guillaume - correct.  But just for that part.  The goal is to implement a complete coding standards enforcer in this solution.  So the console application would include the following steps:  Step 1: Enforce variable member variable naming conventions.  This is the part that requires Roslyn (in order to know which tokens are member variable names that need to be checked).  Step 2: Enforce whitespace requirements.  This is the part that doesn't require Roslyn because it's only looking at the characters used, for instance to replace tab characters with space characters everywhere in the file.

Comment: Will .NormalizeWhiteSpace() work for you, or do you have a whitespace convention different from the .Net one?

Comment: We have a whitespace convention different from the .Net one. (The purpose of this exercise is also to learn the Roslyn limitations/capabilities).

Comment: _"...However, what I'm trying to do is a single solution for all issues..."_ - You don't need Roslyn for that.  Like I said [MPF](http://mpfproj12.codeplex.com/) or [MEF Editor Extensions for Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885013.aspx) can do that for you. It's what I use. I suspect this is what ReSharper does too

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something about MPF or MEF.  From what I've seen, these packages can extend the editor (syntax highlighting, interactive menus for single changes, etc).  They are, in fact, where I started on this effort.  However, I could not find a way in which to make wholesale changes to the file via a menu command (which was my optimum goal), which is why I switched to a console program instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by single entry points.   By itself, Visual Studio knows absolutely nothing about c#; vb.net;  c++; windows like class explorer; specific menu items  or refactoring.  All of that is via VS Language Extensions; extensions or addins.  VS is just a shell written in c++ COM

Comment: You can enumerate an entire file examining the classifications for text which will tell you if it's a keyword, variable, method name and so on